# Django Rest Framework Get Requests With Custom Url

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm just trying to make get request with my field. But in this get request I don't want to use pk. I just want to use Barcode which you can see model below.

Also I'm new on Django:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    barcode = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(13)])
    cover_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    product_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    product_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)

    fields = ['barcode', 'name', 'cover_photo', 'product_url', 'price']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name.encode('utf-8')
```

Also this is my urls.

```
 url(r'^api/products/(?P<barcode>)/$',product_detail, name="product_detail"),
product_detail = views.ProductViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve'
})
```

and this is my view.

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `lookup_field = 'barcode'` in your `ProductViewSet`, i.e.

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = 'barcode'
```

and set regex pattern in urls (mind `[0-9]{1,13}`, it will match any number that its lenght is between 1 and 13):

```
url(r'^api/products/(?P<barcode>[0-9]{1,13})/$',product_detail, name="product_detail")
```

[also checkout code for class GenericAPIView](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/a68b37d8bc432fae37ef5880aec500002b59f565/rest_framework/generics.py#L40)

Comment: I tried your said but now its returning 404. Didn't change anything

Comment: @MuratKaya keep the url as you have kept and try setting the lookup field = 'barcode' in the view.

Comment: @MuratKaya can you send the response.data in both the cases?